# Have Page Method Unhandled Exceptions Behave as Other ASP.Net Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: asp.net, exception, asmx, webforms, pagemethods

I have a webform that has a single page method. My other web apps log unhandled exceptions to the system event log on the web server. Since the other developers that I work with expect to see entries for app errors in the event log, I would like this app to do the same.

However, I have the app send error emails when an exception is caught from calling code inside the page method. It is not writing to the event log when this occurs. Note: the page method re-throws the exception after calling my email notification method.

From what I've read so far it seems that ASP.Net logs errors to the event log by default. I imagine that the same is not true for Page Methods/WebMethods because they basically throw the exception to the client code calling it.

Is there a trivial way to have that exception bubble up properly so that it writes to the event log? No other apps write to the event log directly from what I've seen so I don't think the application could create a new source since our security people keep a lot of things locked down (with good intentions, yay security).

```
[WebMethod]
public static object MyPseudoWebMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // My exception spawning unreliable code here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Cleanup ...
        this.SendErrorNotification(ex);

        throw; // <-- This doesn't bubble up but I'd love for it to!
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't getting handled like the other exceptions? I would assume your app would handle that error just like any other, with the only difference being that the client pages doesn't visibly change. But behind the AJAX call, the webmethod would be throwing an exception, which would make the AJAX response be the YellowScreenOfDeath or whatever custom error page you have, and all the subsequent code would be executed by such a custom error page.

Comment: The error logs do not contain the exceptions but it has exceptions from the other applications. An AJAX call wouldn't render a yellow screen of death though. The page is already loaded, the client javascript calls the webmethod, the webmethod throws an exception and the client javascript detects the error but no exception is logged in the event log.

Comment: You have a "webform that has a single WebMethod"?

Comment: Did some research ... Ok you are sorta right jlafay, but not 100%. WebMethods suffer from a peculiarity in that the HTTP handler for XML Web services swallows the Exception before it hits the global.asax, but 'normal' AJAX calls do not follow that pattern. So if it were not a WebMethod, but just rather an ASPX page that returned a string or something, it would handle the exception in the same was as the other pages in terms of logging. I'll try to think of an answer to get around this.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes. It is a project that I sometimes do work on. It's a very simple internal web app. It's a webform and the code behind has one single WebMethod that calls a WCF service that's part of our middle tier to retrieve entities to pass back to the client.

Comment: The term for what you're referring to is a "Page Method". It's a `static` `[WebMethod]` inside of a page, as opposed to being in its own ASMX file. I do wonder if your method is `static`, though.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes you're correct. And good catch, I didn't copy paste the code and left the static keyword out for the method. I'll edit it to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm interesting problem. You are right in that WebMethod exceptions do NOT follow normal exception flow.

> The Application_Error event is not fired if your web method throws an
>   exception. The reason for this is that the HTTP handler for XML Web
>   services consumes any exception that occurs while an XML Web service
>   is executing and turns it into a SOAP fault prior to the
>   Application_Error event is called.

*(from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2005/09/05/HowToCreateAGlobalExceptionHandlerForAWebService.aspx))*

The above page suggests using a SOAP extension to catch that exception before its swallowed, but here's how I'd do it if you don't want to do that:

1) Make a new 'error recieving' ASPX page that you will build that will take whatever params you want to record in your error log. So for example, have this page take in a POST named "ExceptionDetails" or whatever else you wish to capture. This page will NOT be viewed directly in a browser, so it doesnt need any ASPX controls or anything, but using a MasterPage on it won't hurt anything.

2) In the code behind of this new page, grab whatever POSTS you are sending in and new-up an Exception with whatever details you need. Immediate throw this exception. Doing this means that this exception will follow whatever flow other unhandled exceptions follow in the app (logging, emailing, etc).

3) On the page that calls the WebMethod JS, Wrap the calls to the WebMethod in a try-catch

4) In the catch block, print out whatever message you want in the browser, and initiate a new AJAX post to that new error receiving ASPX page, passing along whatever POST stuff you made that page look for.

The new AJAX call will NOT change ANYTHING in the user's perception by default. The AJAX call fires off a new request to that page, and the ASPX page itself is actually totally unaware that its AJAX and not a normal browser request. Any cookies/session/authentication data that's currently set are available to the AJAXed page as well, if you are recording a user's ID or anything. If you look at the returned response from a tool like Firebug, you will see that its actually the YellowScreenOfDeath's HTML (unless you have a custom 500 page, in which case its that HTML that comes back).

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how the legacy ASMX web services work.

The only workaround is to stop using them (which you should do anyway, unless you're stuck with .NET 2.0). WCF doesn't have this problem.

Comment: This is an old application that I recently did work on. Generally I would prefer WCF over this type of behavior but I think that for this case it may be ok. Mainly because it's one method, it's still working, and WCF config hell isn't necessary for such a simple application.

Comment: WCF config hell no longer exists as of .NET 4.0, BTW.

Comment: I think that's a matter of opinion :) I know it's not the same animal because it's limited to HTTP for protocol choice, but I am much happier with Web API's configuration and ease of implementation.